# Unable to run gcutil from command line

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcutil, gcloud

When I try to install gcutil by following steps on https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/

here is the bin dir contents of C:\gcutil\google-cloud-sdk\bin :

[image]

but gcutil does not seem to install correctly. When I attempt to run gcutil I receive the error :

```
C:\gcutil\google-cloud-sdk\bin>gcutil
'gcutil' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Should gcutil not be a .bat file command ? How can I invoke gcutil ?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to install cygwin unless you need the ssh functionality of gcutil.

The reason you could not initially run gcutil is because it was a python script (and you were not prefixing the command with 'python').  We have since changed this to be a .cmd script, so it should work more natively in windows.  If you add the bin directory to your PATH, you should be able to run gcutil from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

- Download and install Cygwin. Install the 32-bit version.
- Start Cygwin. and download the SDK

  $ curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash | bash
- Restart Cygwin (or cmd).
- Authenticate.

  $ gcloud auth login
- Reset PATH from console.

  setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\full\path\to\google-cloud-sdk\bin"

Or you can use environment variables.

[About variables](https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500)

Answer (score 0):

Installing cygwin to run gcutil if you are working with windows.

https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/ (check the windows tab)

I just do it and work fine.